# Closing Variable Workbook with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a cell range with file paths that are populated using a file browser in the Userform I've created.  These files has rates and tables I will use in the formulas in the "Calculator" workbook.  I have this macro to open the selected workbooks:

```
For i = 1 To 8
If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info & Inputs").Cells(i + 2, 2)) Then
Else
Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info & Inputs").Cells(i + 2, 2).Value)

End If
Next I
```

Which uses the cell values to determine which Files to open.  The cell value is something like this: 
U:\Rating Calculators\New2020\Rates\Rates 2018-10-01.xlsx
which open fine.  However when I am done the whole macro and go to close the workbooks that were opened, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
For i = 1 To 8
If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info & Inputs").Cells(i + 2, 2)) Then
Else
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info & Inputs").Cells(i + 2, 2).Value).Close Savechanges:=False
End If
Next I
```

This does not work, but if I manually type the file path (without the U:/ file path) and just do

```
For i = 1 To 8
If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info & Inputs").Cells(i + 2, 2)) Then
Else
Workbooks("Rates 2018-10-01.xlsx").Close Savechanges:=False
End If
Next I
```

The Close line works, but then it is not a variable and will not close the possibly 1 to 8 files that the macro has opened.  I can't hard code this and do an "If this file is open, close it" because the names might change.

Any easy solution to this? I can't do

```
Workbooks(right(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info & Inputs").Cells(i + 2, 2).Value, 21)).close
```

because the name won't always be "Rates YYYY-MM-DD.xlsx"

Comment: Try assigning a variable `set wb=workbooks.open...` and then you can refer to that in the close line. Not sure what the actual problem is there.

Answer (score 3):

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info & Inputs").Cells(i + 2, 2).Value` returns the full path, like you posted. It returns something like `U:\Rating Calculators\New2020\Rates\Rates 2018-10-01.xlsx` so when you do:

`Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info & Inputs").Cells(i + 2, 2).Value).Close Savechanges:=False`

VBA thinks you are doing something like:
`Workbooks("U:\Rating Calculators\New2020\Rates\Rates 2018-10-01.xlsx").Close Savechanges:=False`

And that's wrong. It should be only the name of opened workbook, not the full path.

You must close each workbook, one by one.

When you open a workbook, you could assign it to a varible defined as `Workbook`. Like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(pathtofile)

wb.Close False
```

The problem is that your code opens several workbooks at same time, you'll need a variable for each one of them.

My suggestion:

Do a loop to close **all workbooks** excep the one that holds the macro (`ThisWorkbook)`.

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then wb.Close False
Next wb
```

Hope this helps